# Weird Android intent-filter pathPattern issue while deep linking

Tags: android, pattern-matching, deep-linking

I want to create deeplinks for these two http urls

> https://sample-app-123.appspot.com/backoffice/#/user_reset_password?email=abc@gmail.com
>   https://sample-app-123.appspot.com/backoffice/#/user_create_password?email=abc@gmail.com

I have gone through various StackOverflow answers, none of them worked. I got to know **PatternMatcher.PATTERN_SIMPLE_GLOB** is used by Android for matching pattern instead of regex expressions.

My manifest looks like

```
<activity android:name=".CreateActivity"
    android:label="Create Password"
    >
    <intent-filter>
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.VIEW"/>
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"></category>
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE"></category>
    <data
        android:host="sample-app-123.appspot.com"
        android:scheme="https"
        android:pathPattern=".*create_password.*"
        />
    </intent-filter>

</activity>
<activity android:name=".ResetActivity"
    android:label="Reset Password"
    >
    <intent-filter>
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.VIEW"/>
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"></category>
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE"></category>
    <data
        android:host="sample-app-123.appspot.com"
        android:scheme="https"
        android:pathPattern=".*reset_password.*"
        />
    </intent-filter>
</activity>
```

I have created several tests for checking **PatternMatcher.PATTERN_SIMPLE_GLOB**, All tests are PASSED, i am clueless why its not working

```
public void testPatternMatcher() throws Exception {
    PatternMatcher mPatternMatcher;

    mPatternMatcher = new PatternMatcher("https://sample-app-123.appspot.com/backoffice\\/#\\/user_create_password.*", PatternMatcher.PATTERN_SIMPLE_GLOB);
    assertTrue(mPatternMatcher.match("https://sample-app-123.appspot.com/backoffice/#/user_create_password?email=abc@gmail.com"));
    assertFalse(mPatternMatcher.match("https://sample-app-123.appspot.com/backoffice/#/user_reset_password?email=abc@gmail.com"));

    mPatternMatcher = new PatternMatcher(".*user_create_password.*", PatternMatcher.PATTERN_SIMPLE_GLOB);
    assertTrue(mPatternMatcher.match("https://sample-app-123.appspot.com/backoffice/#/user_create_password?email=abc@gmail.com"));
    assertFalse(mPatternMatcher.match("https://sample-app-123.appspot.com/backoffice/#/user_reset_password?email=abc@gmail.com"));

    mPatternMatcher = new PatternMatcher(".*user_reset_password.*", PatternMatcher.PATTERN_SIMPLE_GLOB);
    assertFalse(mPatternMatcher.match("/backoffice/#/user_create_password?email=abc@gmail.com"));
    assertTrue(mPatternMatcher.match("/backoffice/#/user_reset_password?email=abc@gmail.com"));
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`create_password` or `reset_password` are not part of the uri path.
The uri path ends just before the `#` character. This is a special character that delimits the `query` from the `hash` (or anchor).

scheme: `https://`
host: `sample-app-123.appspot.com`
path: `/backoffice/`
fragment `#/user_reset_password?email=abc@gmail.com`

You should instead use url like:

```
https://sample-app-123.appspot.com/backoffice/user_reset_password?email=abc@gmail.com
https://sample-app-123.appspot.com/backoffice/user_create_password?email=abc@gmail.com
```

This will work as expected.

scheme: `https://`
host: `sample-app-123.appspot.com`
path: `/backoffice/user_create_password`
query: `email=abc@gmail.com`

Comment: You are right, # was creating issue, anyways url is not under my control, so can't remove it from url

Comment: In this case you can catch all URLs and route them differently depending on their content